# Node.js build error. ReferenceError: module is not defined in ES module scope This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js'

Tags: javascript, node.js

I do "npm run build", but it show error

these are my error report

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/webpack.config.js' config
[webpack-cli] ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/webpack.config.js:1:14
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:185:25)
    at async Promise.all (index 0)
    at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:281:24)
    at async importModuleDynamicallyWrapper (node:internal/vm/module:437:15)
    at async WebpackCLI.tryRequireThenImport (/Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:232:34)
    at async loadConfigByPath (/Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1406:27)
    at async WebpackCLI.loadConfig (/Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1515:38)
    at async WebpackCLI.createCompiler (/Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1781:22)
    at async WebpackCLI.runWebpack (/Users/chenyuqi/gptexpress/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js:1877:20)
```

And this is my `webpack.config.js`

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: './app.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'final.js',
  },
  target: 'node',
};
```

and there is my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "gptexpress",
  "version": "1.0.2",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon app.js",
    "eslint": "eslint ./",
    "eslint-fix": "eslint ./ --fix",
    "build": "webpack",
    "start": "node app.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "node-fetch": "^2.7.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/core": "^7.23.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.20",
    "@types/node": "^20.8.2",
    "eslint": "^8.50.0",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "webpack": "^5.88.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "type": "module"
}
```

I'd like to deploy this project on Azure as an API but I can't build him in Local and I can't build him in Azure.

I could run dev and start success, but build is error.

Comment: can you show your `package.json` file ?

Comment: Sure I already post it on my question

Comment: Can you remove ` "type": "module"` from package.json and try?

Comment: It works! Amazing!